# cant access ubuntu localhost which hosts apache openmeeting from internet

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu-18.04, openmeetings

I'm new and selflerner. I have configured a apache open meeting in ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu has been installed as VM guest using windows server 2016. Open meeting is running on ubuntu local host properly. Both guest and host has two separate public IPs, x.x.x.155, x.x.x.157. I can ping those from internet. All the firewalls and virus guards has been disabled. If I try x.x.x.155/localhost, from internet I only get a error. Host and guest can ping each other but host cant access guest localhost. What am I doing wrong. Is there any place or script to configure. Any advice will be highly appreciated

I did not install Apache server. When I start the openmeeting from terminal, it shows tomcat has started. I do not have to edit NAT in router since I have public static ips.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I just found out that it should be done through editing hosts file.